# Finding a path via different records in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a MySQL table which has the following fields

- ID
- fromID
- toID

example data:

```
ID      fromID      toID
-------------------------
24610   12512       76122
76122   24610       34671
90127   35167       12523
34671   76122       1512
```

In the end, I want the full path from 24610 to 34671. Is this possible with pure SQL?

I would to it in my code and search for every record after receiving the `toID`, which is not really performant.

Comment: I'm removing my answer, see this link: http://explainextended.com/2009/07/20/hierarchical-data-in-mysql-parents-and-children-in-one-query/

Comment: I'll look into this tomorow after heaving some sleep. Looks really advanced to me.

Comment: yes it is, probably to 95% of mysql users as well. But since there's no analytic functions in mysql that's your only solution without transforming your model.

Comment: what is your expected output?